# Plotting something halfway through a for loop - python

Tags: python

I'm running a model of a spring in python using a for loop over 50 iterations and want to plot it after 25 iterations, and again after 50 iterations.

Here's an excerpt of the code I've been using so far (I can post the whole thing if that would be helpful).

```
ts = np.array([0])
xs = f(ts)

for i in range(50):
    tn = ts[i]+0.1
    xn = f(tn)
    ts = np.append(ts,tn)
    xs = np.append(xs,xn)
    while i == 24:
        plt.plot(ts,xs)
        plt.savefig('Weight plotted after 2.5 seconds.png')
    while i == 49:
        plt.plot(ts,xs)
        plt.savefig('Spring plotted after 5 seconds.png')
```

I'm not getting any errors but it's just not returning anything. I'm pretty new to python and coding in general so any input that anyone might have would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `while` statements with `if` statements.

`while` will repeat the indented code as long as the condition `i == 24` is satisfied. Once your loop reaches `i == 24`, the program will repeatedly save your figure until you terminate the program because `i` does not change within the `while` loop.

`if` will execute the indented code once if the condition is satisfied--which is what you want.

Comment: Ah, that should have been obvious... Thanks for your help I got it working there!